# meteor pcel:mysql - How can i return response to client

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, meteor

Please i have been trying to return data to client on meteor and i get "**undefined**" always.
I think am mixing up **"synchronous and asynchronous"** way of outputting response but its driving me crazy here.

Please can someone help out.
here is my client code:

```
//BASE FUNCTIONS
Template.Home.events({

  "submit #login-form": function(){
      var formname = 'login-form';

        var form = $('form[name='+formname+']');
        var username = form.find('input[name=email]').val();
        var password = form.find('input[name=password]').val();

        var user = {'email':username, 'pass':password};

        Meteor.call('AccessUser', user, function(err, resp){
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
          }
          console.log(resp);
          //FlowRouter.go('/admin');
        });

  }

});
```

and here is my method running on server :

```
Meteor.methods({

  //Login User
  AccessUser(user){

    var que = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE USERNAME = "'+connection.escape(user.email)+'" AND PASSWORD = "'+connection.escape(user.pass)+'" AND ID = 1';

      connection.query(que, function(err, rows){
        if(err){
          // return err.code;
          return err;
        }

        if(rows.length > 0){
          return 1;
        }else{
          return 0;
        }
        connection.end();
      });

  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit,  comrade

Comment: Found a solution : https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/1465